# why does g++ fail to compile. when taking the address of a templated member function of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class X
{
public:
  template <typename Y>
  void x();
};

template<typename T>
class Z
{
public:
  void x()
  {
    void (X<Z>::*p)() = &X<Z>::x<T>;    
  }
};
```

g++ 4.8.1

How do I get this to compile please;
I have tried many variants but get the following errors

```
t.C:15:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
                                   ^
t.C:15:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 4):

When a dependent name is a template, you need the `template` keyword:

```
void (X<Z>::*p)() = &X<Z>::template x<T>;
```

If you don't the compiler thinks `x` is a normal variable that is a member of `X`, because it doesn't check. You must explicitly inform the compiler that the name is a template. It is the counterpart to the `typename` keyword used to disambiguate type names from variables names.

Comment: That works.  Thanks for replying so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`X<Z>::x` is a dependent name (i.e. its meaning depends on the template parameter `Z`), so you have to specify that `x` is a template:

```
void (X<Z>::*p)() = &X<Z>::template x<T>;
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's a very clear answer.  I've never seen that before.